# Transformer near signal lines

Tags: power-supply, analog, signal-processing

I am currently building an analog signal audio device and am designing a power supply to take mains in and convert it to +/-12VDC.

I have experience designing power supply units but not in the same enclosure as the signal processing components. My concern is the placement of this power supply unit and the effect it will have on the signal lines.

Are there best practices for ensuring there is no noise or mains hum added to the signal by the transformer? I am struggling to find resources available for this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're planning to use a  linear power supply with a mains step down transformer, a toroid power transformer will have the least stray field.

If a toroid transformer is not available, you can shield an EI transformer with mu-metal to minimize stray magnetic fields.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **just** the power input HOT wire. At 1 amp average, or 10 amps peak into the rectifiers, that current peak occurring in 10 microSeconds, how much trash is induced into a 1cm square loop located 10cm away from the HOT wire?

Vinduce = MU0 * MUr * Area/Distance * dI/dT

For air, this becomes

Vinduce = 2e-7 * Area/Distance * dI/dT

and area = 0.01 * 0.01 = 1e-4, distance = 0.1, 
and dI/dT = 10amp/10uS = 1e6amp/sec

Now insert these values into the formula

Vinduce = 2e-7 * 1e-4 / 0.1 * 1e+6 = 2e-7 * e-3 * e+6 = 1e-10+6 = 1e-4

Vinduce = 100 microVolts of 120Hz peak-rectified-current narrow-pulse

And this is just from the HOT wire being 4" (0.1 meter) from your circuit.

How lucky do you feel?

Here is a 3-stage simulation, gain of approx. 1,000 and input of 1milliVolts,
with 60Hz input at 1Million Amp/second slewrate of the 60Hz.

Notice the output SNR is only 4dB, thus the signal is only 1.6x the magnetic interference.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Very very useful and bookmarked. 

I am a mechanical engineer teaching myself electronics in my spare time so things like this I find hard to find resources on.